# Nans in Winsorizing

Tags: r, trim, outliers

I have an issue running winsorizing function in r. For some columns, it did work, but for some others, it just returned Nan. I checked the columns, they are all numeric and do not have any Na or, Inf, or Nans.

I would be thankful if you have any suggestions.
These are lines of winsorizing:

```
library(robustbase)
library(parallel)
library(ggplot2)
library(perry)
library(robustHD)


DataY1$ExplorationW<-0
DataY1$ExplorationW<-winsorize(DataY1$Exploration, minval = NULL, maxval = NULL, probs = c(0.05, 0.95))

DataY1$AmbidexteritynewW<-0
DataY1$AmbidexteritynewW<-winsorize(DataY1$Ambidexteritynew, minval = NULL, maxval = NULL, probs = c(0.05, 0.95))
```

for this one, `DataY1$ExplorationW` winsorizes work, but for `DataY1$AmbidexteritynewW` no.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the data standardized as indicated on the manual page: "Data cleaning weights are only meaningful for standardized data. In the general case, the data need to be standardized first, then the data cleaning weights can be computed and applied to the standardized data, after which the cleaned standardized data need to be backtransformed to the original scale."

Comment: Yes, they are standardized. I have used psych library and it did work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found another library, which I post here that might be helpful for others.

library(psych)
DataY1$ExploitationW = psych::winsor(DataY1$Exploitation, trim = 0.02)